# argparse option arg using nargs='?' before positional arg in subparser

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--optional',
    default=None,
    const='some-const',
    nargs='?',
    help='optional')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

subparser = subparsers.add_parser('subparser')

subparser.add_argument(
    'positional',
    help='positional')

args = parser.parse_args()

print args

./test.py --optional opt subparser positional
Namespace(optional='opt', positional='positional')  <-- works as expected

./test.py --optional subparser positional
usage: test.py [-h] [--optional [OPTIONAL]] {subparser} ...
test.py: error: invalid choice: 'positional' (choose from 'subparser')  <-- throws an error
 Namespace(optional='some-const', positional='positional')  <-- would expect to see this
```

Above is my simplest test code to demonstrate this problem.  I would like to have an optional arg using nargs='?' and const *before* my positional arg in the subparser.  I have read that I can pass the original parser as a parent to the child subparser, but this doesn't solve the problem.  I have tried adding add_help=False and conflict_handler='resolve' to the initial parser declaration when I tried that.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Why doesn't defining `--optional` as a parent of the subparser solve the problem?  You have to call `subparser` anyway, so what difference does it make if you call it `--optional subparser POS` or `subparser POS --optional`?  I hesitant to call it a "bug", but, in my reading of the documentation and playing around, it does defy my expectations :)  Still, if you can work around it...

Comment: `subparser POS --optional` doesn't work either, with this code.

Answer (score 1):

When parsing `./test.py --optional foo bar`, argparse sees an optional string (starts with --) followed by two argument strings (no --)

So it starts by processing `--optional`.  It's nargs is a 'greedy ?', so it consumes the `foo` argument, producing:

```
Namespace('optional'='foo')
```

That leaves `bar` to be consumed as a subcommand argument.

It does not check if `foo` is a valid subcommand argument.

The same reasoning applies to `./test.py --optional subparser positional`.

Answer (score 0):

This throws an error:

```
.test.py --optional
```

Because `subparser` is not optional:

```
usage: subparser.py [-h] [--optional [OPTIONAL]] {subparser} ...
test.py: error: too few arguments
```

`subparser` is getting eaten up and used as `OPTIONAL` in your second example.  I don't understand why, other than argparse isn't figuring out in advance that subparser is a subparser.

This is the closest thing I could make to what you are describing:

```
import argparse

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent_parser.add_argument(
    '--optional',
    nargs='?',
    default=None,
    const='some-const',
    help='optional')

sub_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parent_parser])
sub_parser.add_argument('--subparser', required=True)

args = sub_parser.parse_args()

print args
```

I think you've uncovered a bug.